# Swift: Handling Facebook token errors

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to handle events when the Facebook token is invalidated. For example when the user changes the Facebook password. When I use:

```
FBSDKAccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessToken
```

and the user changes the password, I would get the

```
Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password.
```

The error looks like this:

```
com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 190;
        "error_subcode" = 460;
        "fbtrace_id" = HFdKjQiGR0m;
        message = "Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password.";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
};
code = 400;
}, NSLocalizedRecoveryOptions=(
    OK,
    Cancel
)}
```

How can I validate these error codes so I can take the appropriate action?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`FBSDKGraphRequestConnection.h`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKGraphRequestConnection.h) that contains a completion handler type (`FBSDKGraphRequestHandler`). This completion handler gives you a result and error you can parse to get the message and then do what you need.